# Diacritic difference: "This" v. "These"

Tags: pronunciation

I have a hard time pronouncing `This is`, and making it sound different than `*These* is`. I guess I relax the `s` sound at the end of `this`, blending it with the `i` as in `/thiziz/`.

I wonder if this is a problem of inflection or pausing; or if it is really an issue with making the last `s` non-sounding (not a `z` sound).

It could also be that native speakers make the diacritic sound in the `i` versus the `e` in `these`. I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong to say "these is" since these can refer to a plural, 
"these are" is correct

as for pronunciation, most people will say:

- "this": [this] and not [thiz].
- "these": [theeze] (rhymes with cheese)

"this-iz" vs "theeze-iz"

Comment: Of course it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: i figured but decided to leave it in since someone else might read this.

Comment: Why "theeze-is"? Why would anybody pronounce "is" as `\is\`?

Comment: my fault, fixed.

Comment: Are you really going to leave that as *these is* rather than *these are*? You're doing the asker a disservice.

Comment: the first sentence of my answer says the correction.... (i also mention it in the comments above you)